# Angular filter confusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

So I have a list of users in my firebase. Now I am showing every user like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.username" placeholder="{{ 'SEARCH_USERS' | translate}}" class="form-control"> <br/>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users | usernameFilter:search.username ">
        <a href="#/report/{{user.username}}">{{user.username}}: {{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}}</a> <br/>
    </li>
</ul>
<p ng-show="error" >{{error}}</p>
```

Search.username or search makes no difference, the filter does nothing. This is what my users reference looks like:

```
Object {$id: "users", $bind: function, $add: function, $save: function, $set: function…}
$add: function (item) {
$auth: function (token) {
$bind: function (scope, name, defaultFn) {
$child: function (key) {
$getIndex: function () {
$getRef: function () {
$id: "users"
$off: function (type, callback) {
$on: function (type, callback) {
$remove: function (key) {
$save: function (key) {
$set: function (newValue) {
$transaction: function (updateFn, applyLocally) {
$update: function (newValue) {
Battle: Object
Litchy: Object
Robin: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Battle, Litchy and Robin are all users. I want to know how I can filter this list by username, the easy way from the AngularJS docs example doesn't seem to be working here since I do not have an explicit username property on my reference.

EDIT: Firebase structure screenshot:

[image: firebase]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correclty, you want to filter "by key".
Angular's `filter` filter filters the "values" of the iterated object, but you can use a custom filter to filter by key:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | byKey:search.username">

app.filter('byKey', function () {
    return function (obj, username) {
        if (!username) { return obj; }
        username = username.toLowerCase();

        var filtered = {};
        angular.forEach(obj, function (value, key) {
            if (key.toLowerCase().indexOf(username) !== -1) {
                filtered[key] = value;
            }
        });
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

<sub>**Note:**
I have implemented the filter to perform case-insensitive, substring match.

You should modify it according to your requirements.</sub>

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/gJ7ka/)**.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work completely, he filters out everything once I type in a single letter. I will take a closer look

Comment: Wait, it does filter correctly but the user object goes empty once I type in a single letter

Comment: @RobinHellemans: I am not sure what you mean. Did you try my demo ? Does it happen there ? (I don't see anything getting emtpy.)

Comment: Yes I tried exactly the same thing as you, I will update the original post with my firebase to make it more clear

Comment: And you say that the objects get empty once filtered ? That's strange. Could you create a fiddle or something ?

Comment: I updated my js code, I have no knowledge of fiddle I'm afraid

Answer (score 2):

@ExpertSystem offered some great insights into the workings of angular's filter methods. You can also convert your $firebase object to an ordered array using `orderByPriority`, which works quite a bit simpler with Angular's filter tools:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | orderByPriority | usernameFilter:search.username ">
    <a href="#/report/{{user.username}}">{{user.username}}: {{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}}</a> <br/>
</li>
```

Also note that orderByPriority will probably be replaced with some more advanced array tools ($asArray) in an upcoming AngularFire release.